# Message exchange between Paho java & javascript client not happening

Tags: mqtt, iot, paho

How can I send a message from paho java client to paho javascript client.

```
    String topic        = "chatWith/904";
    String content      = "Message from MqttPublishSample";
    int qos             = 0;
    String broker       = "tcp://127.0.0.1:1883";
    String clientId     = "JavaSample";
    MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();

    try {
        MqttClient sampleClient = new MqttClient(broker, clientId, persistence);
        MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
        connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
        System.out.println("Connecting to broker: "+broker);
        sampleClient.connect(connOpts);
        System.out.println("Connected");
        System.out.println("Publishing message: "+content);
        MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(content.getBytes());
        message.setQos(qos);
        sampleClient.publish(topic, message);
        System.out.println("Message published");
        sampleClient.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Disconnected");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch(MqttException me) {
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Message exchange between two JS client is happening. But between Javasript & java client, message exchange is not happening.

Here is JS code

```
 client = new Messaging.Client(host, Number(port), clientId);

  client.onConnect = onConnect;

  client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
  client.onMessageDelivered = onMessageDelivered;
  client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;            
 var willMessage = createByteMessage({
        id: '',
        'msgType':'USER_STATUS',
        'status': 'Offline',
        'senderId': myUserId,
        'senderName': myName
    }, statusTopic);    
    willMessage.retained = true;  

  client.connect({
    userName:user, 
    password:password, 
    onSuccess:onConnect, 
    onFailure:onFailure,
    'willMessage': willMessage
  });
```

Here port is 8083 and mqtt broker is [emqtt](http://emqtt.io)

`client.config`

```
testclientid0
testclientid1 127.0.0.1
testclientid2 192.168.0.1/24
```

`emqttd.config`

```
% -*- mode: erlang;erlang-indent-level: 4;indent-tabs-mode: nil -*-
%% ex: ft=erlang ts=4 sw=4 et
[{kernel, [
    {start_timer, true},
    {start_pg2, true}
 ]},
 {sasl, [
    {sasl_error_logger, {file, "log/emqttd_sasl.log"}}
 ]},
 {ssl, [
    %{versions, ['tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1']}
 ]},
 {lager, [
    {colored, true},
    {async_threshold, 5000},
    {error_logger_redirect, false},
    {crash_log, "log/emqttd_crash.log"},
    {handlers, [
        %%{lager_console_backend, info},
        %%NOTICE: Level >= error
        %%{lager_emqtt_backend, error},
        {lager_file_backend, [
            {formatter_config, [time, " ", pid, " [",severity,"] ", message, "\n"]},
            {file, "log/emqttd_error.log"},
            {level, error},
            {size, 104857600},
            {date, "$D0"},
            {count, 30}
        ]}
    ]}
 ]},
 {esockd, [
    {logger, {lager, error}}
 ]},
 {emqttd, [
    %% Authentication and Authorization
    {access, [
        %% Authetication. Anonymous Default
        {auth, [
            %% Authentication with username, password
            %{username, []},

            %% Authentication with clientid
            %{clientid, [{password, no}, {file, "etc/clients.config"}]},

            %% Authentication with LDAP
            % {ldap, [
            %    {servers, ["localhost"]},
            %    {port, 389},
            %    {timeout, 30},
            %    {user_dn, "uid=$u,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"},
            %    {ssl, fasle},
            %    {sslopts, [
            %        {"certfile", "ssl.crt"},
            %        {"keyfile", "ssl.key"}]}
            % ]},

            %% Allow all
            {anonymous, []}
        ]},
        %% ACL config
        {acl, [
            %% Internal ACL module
            {internal,  [{file, "etc/acl.config"}, {nomatch, allow}]}
        ]}
    ]},
    %% MQTT Protocol Options
    {mqtt, [
        %% Packet
        {packet, [
            %% Max ClientId Length Allowed
            {max_clientid_len, 512},
            %% Max Packet Size Allowed, 64K default
            {max_packet_size, 65536}
        ]},
        %% Client
        {client, [
            %% Socket is connected, but no 'CONNECT' packet received
            {idle_timeout, 30} %% seconds
        ]},
        %% Session
        {session, [
            %% Max number of QoS 1 and 2 messages that can be “in flight” at one time.
            %% 0 means no limit
            {max_inflight, 100},

            %% Retry interval for redelivering QoS1/2 messages.
            {unack_retry_interval, 60},

            %% Awaiting PUBREL Timeout
            {await_rel_timeout, 20},

            %% Max Packets that Awaiting PUBREL, 0 means no limit
            {max_awaiting_rel, 0},

            %% Statistics Collection Interval(seconds)
            {collect_interval, 0},

            %% Expired after 2 day (unit: minute)
            {expired_after, 2880}

        ]},
        %% Queue
        {queue, [
            %% simple | priority
            {type, simple},

            %% Topic Priority: 0~255, Default is 0
            %% {priority, [{"topic/1", 10}, {"topic/2", 8}]},

            %% Max queue length. Enqueued messages when persistent client disconnected,
            %% or inflight window is full.
            {max_length, infinity},

            %% Low-water mark of queued messages
            {low_watermark, 0.2},

            %% High-water mark of queued messages
            {high_watermark, 0.6},

            %% Queue Qos0 messages?
            {queue_qos0, true}
        ]}
    ]},
    %% Broker Options
    {broker, [
        %% System interval of publishing broker $SYS messages
        {sys_interval, 60},

        %% Retained messages
        {retained, [
            %% Expired after seconds, never expired if 0
            {expired_after, 0},

            %% Max number of retained messages
            {max_message_num, 100000},

            %% Max Payload Size of retained message
            {max_playload_size, 65536}
        ]},

        %% PubSub and Router
        {pubsub, [
            %% Default should be scheduler numbers
            {pool_size, 8},

            %% Store Subscription: true | false
            {subscription, true},

            %% Route aging time(seconds)
            {route_aging, 5}
        ]},

        %% Bridge
        {bridge, [
            %%TODO: bridge queue size
            {max_queue_len, 10000},

            %% Ping Interval of bridge node
            {ping_down_interval, 1} %seconds
        ]}
    ]},
    %% Modules
    {modules, [
        %% Client presence management module.
        %% Publish messages when client connected or disconnected
        {presence, [{qos, 0}]},

        %% Subscribe topics automatically when client connected
        {subscription, [

            %% $c will be replaced by clientid
            %% {"$queue/clients/$c", 1},

            %% Static subscriptions from backend
            backend
        ]}

        %% Rewrite rules
        %% {rewrite, [{file, "etc/rewrite.config"}]}
    ]},
    %% Plugins
    {plugins, [
        %% Plugin App Library Dir
        {plugins_dir, "./plugins"},

        %% File to store loaded plugin names.
        {loaded_file, "./data/loaded_plugins"}
    ]},

    %% Listeners
    {listeners, [
        {mqtt, 1883, [
            %% Size of acceptor pool
            {acceptors, 16},

            %% Maximum number of concurrent clients
            {max_clients, 512},

            %% Socket Access Control
            {access, [{allow, all}]},

            %% Connection Options
            {connopts, [
                %% Rate Limit. Format is 'burst, rate', Unit is KB/Sec
                %% {rate_limit, "100,10"} %% 100K burst, 10K rate
            ]},

            %% Socket Options
            {sockopts, [
                %Set buffer if hight thoughtput
                %{recbuf, 4096},
                %{sndbuf, 4096},
                %{buffer, 4096},
                %{nodelay, true},
                {backlog, 1024}
            ]}
        ]},

        {mqtts, 8883, [
            %% Size of acceptor pool
            {acceptors, 4},

            %% Maximum number of concurrent clients
            {max_clients, 512},

            %% Socket Access Control
            {access, [{allow, all}]},

            %% SSL certificate and key files
            {ssl, [{certfile, "etc/ssl/ssl.crt"},
                   {keyfile,  "etc/ssl/ssl.key"}]},

            %% Socket Options
            {sockopts, [
                {backlog, 1024}
                %{buffer, 4096},
            ]}
        ]},
        %% WebSocket over HTTPS Listener
        %% {https, 8083, [
        %%  %% Size of acceptor pool
        %%  {acceptors, 4},
        %%  %% Maximum number of concurrent clients
        %%  {max_clients, 512},
        %%  %% Socket Access Control
        %%  {access, [{allow, all}]},
        %%  %% SSL certificate and key files
        %%  {ssl, [{certfile, "etc/ssl/ssl.crt"},
        %%         {keyfile,  "etc/ssl/ssl.key"}]},
        %%  %% Socket Options
        %%  {sockopts, [
        %%      %{buffer, 4096},
        %%      {backlog, 1024}
        %%  ]}
        %%]},

        %% HTTP and WebSocket Listener
        {http, 8083, [
            %% Size of acceptor pool
            {acceptors, 4},
            %% Maximum number of concurrent clients
            {max_clients, 64},
            %% Socket Access Control
            {access, [{allow, all}]},
            %% Socket Options
            {sockopts, [
                {backlog, 1024}
                %{buffer, 4096},
            ]}
        ]}
    ]},

    %% Erlang System Monitor
    {sysmon, [
        %% Long GC, don't monitor in production mode for:
        %% https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/feb45017da36be78d4c5784d758ede619fa7bfd3/erts/emulator/beam/erl_gc.c#L421
        {long_gc, false},

        %% Long Schedule(ms)
        {long_schedule, 240},

        %% 8M words. 32MB on 32-bit VM, 64MB on 64-bit VM.
        %% 8 * 1024 * 1024
        {large_heap, 8388608},

        %% Busy Port
        {busy_port, false},

        %% Busy Dist Port
        {busy_dist_port, true}

    ]}
 ]}
].
```

Comment: Does the JS client connect sauccessfully?, i.e do your javascript onSuccess/onConnect or onFailure/onFailure callback functions get called when the client tries to connect?

Comment: yes between two JS client its working find but between JS & JAVA  client its not exchanging messages

Comment: Do you mean "Yes the JS client is succeeding when it tries to connect because onSuccess is called"?

Comment: Shouldn't you include onMessageArrived in the client.connect() parameter?

Comment: r u talking about JS ? In js it is still there